# Odoo doesn't show the field label in xpath

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I'm adding a custom string field (stock_value) to the 'product.supplierinfo' module in Odoo enterprise 11 but I can't get it to display the label correctly.

I inherited the module and then added a new field to the module and to the view trough xpath.

**Problem:** the string related to the new field is not shown.

**Module:**

```
class class_name(models.Model):
    _inherit                        = 'product.supplierinfo'
    stock_value                     = fields.Integer(string="Stock")
```

**View:**

```
<!-- Stock value in the vendors -->
<record id="view_product_product_supplierinfo_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.supplierinfo.product.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.supplierinfo</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_supplierinfo_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='price']" position="after">
        <field name="stock_value" />
    </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

**Result:** as you can see theres a zero bellow the price value but the string label 'Stock' is not shown.

[image]

**Other thing is tried:**

Adding the next code:

```
<separator />
<label for="stock_value" string="Stock Value"/>
```

Gives me

[image]

Putting the field inside a group gives me

[image]

I also tried changing the position to 'before' in this last view but I cannot manage to make it look as it should. I tried using @string but that no longer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the field `price` is inside a `div` container, so you have to put your field after this `div` (which is the parent of the field `price` in the DOM). Thus, you have to tell `xpath` that you want to put your field after the DOM parent of the field `price`, not just after the field as you have in your code. Depending on the style you are looking for, you can select any of the following options:

**Option 1** (you could add `class="oe_inline` to your field too"):

```
<!-- Stock value in the vendors -->
<record id="view_product_product_supplierinfo_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.supplierinfo.product.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.supplierinfo</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_supplierinfo_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='price']/.." position="after">
            <label for="stock_value"/>
            <div>
                <field name="stock_value"/>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

**Option 2**:

```
<!-- Stock value in the vendors -->
<record id="view_product_product_supplierinfo_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.supplierinfo.product.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.supplierinfo</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_supplierinfo_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='price']/.." position="after">
            <field name="stock_value"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I think you added the same code twice. :D Either way it worked. I had no idea I was able to do that. Thank you very much.

Comment: I did :D I updated the answer to correct that just in case you prefer the style of the second option. You are welcome!